# Como guardo un diccionario para no perder su contenido?

Tags: python

Estaba creando un simple programa para poder repasar palabras en inglés y me surgió una duda.

¿Como puedo guardar las palabras introducidas en el diccionario creado para una futura sesión? . Al cerrar el programa y volver a abrir se eliminan todas las palabras del diccionario.

He probado a guardarlo en un archivo.txt pero a la hora de leer el archivo para extraer el diccionario da muchos problemas.

¿Se podría guardar la caché generada en la sesión y volverla a ejecutar la siguiente vez que cargue el programa para no perder el diccionario?

¿O quizás se podría utilizar alguna librería o alguna otra opción que yo no conozca?

Me gustaría que fuese en un archivo y no recurrir a bases de datos como MySQL.

```
#!/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def repasar():
    while True:
        for d in x:
            print ("palabra: %s" %(d))
            ing = input("Escribe en ingles: ")

            if ing == dic.get(d):
                print ("correcto")
            else:
                print ("Incorrecto: %s" %(ing))

def agregar():
    x=input("Palabra en español: ")
    y=input("Palabra en ingles: ")
    dic[x]=y
    print (dic)

dic={}

print ("1. Repasar")
print ("2. Añadir palabra")
decision = input("Que quieres hacer? ")


if decision == "1":
    repasar()
elif decision == "2":
    agregar()
```

PD: Pongo el programa por si es necesario para encontrar solución. Se puede ver que esta sin terminar, lo he dejado así hasta que encuentre una solución al problema citado.

Comment: "me gustaría no tener que recurrir a bases de datos" suena a que quieres seguir siendo novato :P Vamos, que no es tan dificil , que problemas te da al leer el txt ? puedes hacer una pregunta con éso en especifico y aprendes manipulación de archivos antes de Bases de Datos

Comment: `archivo=open("dic.txt","r")
texto = archivo.read()

dic={texto}

print dic["hola"]`   cuando lo ejecuto me da error y en el archivo pone "hola":"hello" , también he probado guardando dic={"hola":"hello"} en el archivo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si no quieres usar bases de datos ([`sqlite`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) viene incluida en la biblioteca estándar y es muy sencillo usarla) puedes usar [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) o `cpickle` para serializar objetos Python.

De esta forma guardas el diccionario en un archivo y al iniciar tu programa lo cargas. Así te evitas leer y parsear manualmente un txt o csv para construir tu diccionario.

Me he tomado la libertad de modificar algunas cosas más en tu código pero la idea del uso de `pickle` está en dos funciones:

- `cargar_datos()`: intenta abrir el archivo de datos (`traducciones.dat`). Si existe lo carga y retorna el diccionario de la sesión anterior. Si no existe retorna un diccionario vacío.
- `guardar_datos()`: usa `pickle.dump()` para guardar el diccionario actual para que esté disponible en futuras sesiones.

El código quedaría:

```
#!/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pickle


def repasar(dic):
    for es, ing in dic.items():
        resp = input('Escribe en ingles "{}": '.format(es))
        if resp == ing:
            print ("Correcto.")
        else:
            print ('Incorrecto, es "{}".'.format(ing))

def agregar(dic):
    x = input("Palabra en español: ")
    y = input("Palabra en ingles: ")
    dic[x] = y

def cargar_datos():
    try:
        with open("traducciones.dat", "rb") as f:
            return pickle.load(f)
    except (OSError, IOError) as e:
        return dict()

def guardar_datos(dic):
    with open("traducciones.dat", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(dic, f)


def main():
    dic = cargar_datos()
    menu ='''
    1. Repasar.
    2. Añadir palabra.
    3. Guardar y salir.
    '''

    while True:
        print(menu)
        decision = input("¿Que quieres hacer?: ")
        if decision == "1":
            repasar(dic)
        elif decision == "2":
            agregar(dic)
        elif decision == "3":
            guardar_datos(dic)
            break
        else:
            print('Opción inválida, intentelo de nuevo.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

La opción de `sqlite3` es mucho más eficiente si vas a terminar con diccionarios muy grandes. La opción más 'básica' es usar un txt o un csv y construir con el diccionario. Te podrías ayudar del módulo [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) para ello, pero eso lo dejo a tu elección.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me sirven las soluciones que me has dado y gracias por tomarte las molestias de modificar el código, mirando las modificaciones he aprendido un par de cosas más. Muchas gracias.